# SwiftUI crashes preview when pass parameters to the view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

```swift
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct CategoryOverview: View {
    var category: Category
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            HStack {
                Text(category.name ?? "")
                    .font(.title)
                Spacer()
            }
            Text(String(category.records?.count ?? 0))
                .font(.subheadline)
        }
        .padding()
        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        .background(Color.blue)
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
    }
}

struct CategoryOverview_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let category = Category()
        category.id = UUID()
        category.timestamp = Date()
        category.name = "Clean"

        return CategoryOverview(category: category)
    }
}
```

I defined `Category` entity in Core Data model. Then I built a simple view to show the name of a category. I tried to pass a `Category` instance to the preview struct, but preview crashed always. There is no detail logs for this crash. It just said "the preview process appears to have crashed".

This view works well in other views such as main `ContentView`. So, the code is fine, but I suspect that my preview code is wrong.

I'm very new to Swift and Swift UI. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Category` is a Core Data model you need a `context`

change

```
let category = Category()
```

To something like

```
let category = Category(context: PersistentController.preview.container.viewContext)
```

If you use the standard setup. If not just fill in the context variable whichever way you traditionally use it.